# Kotlin Timer.schedule starts two tasks

Tags: android, kotlin, schedule, timertask

While writing an Android application in Kotlin, I use `Timer.schedule` and `TimerTask` classes. But, `Timer.schedule` starts two tasks.

This is my code:

```
var count = 0
val timer = Timer()
val task = object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        println("${this} : $count")
        count++
    }
}
timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000)
```

My code gives me this result:

```
PackageName.ClassName$task@f4bd15 : 0
PackageName.ClassName$task@3651fb6 : 0
PackageName.ClassName$task@f4bd15 : 1
PackageName.ClassName$task@3651fb6 : 1
PackageName.ClassName$task@f4bd15 : 2
PackageName.ClassName$task@3651fb6 : 2
...
```

It starts two tasks. When I try to `task.cancel`, just one task was canceled. The other one is still alive.

How can I start only one task?

Comment: I doubt it's `timer.schedule` that starts two tasks. You're probably executing the lines you posted twice somehow. Put some logs around them and check. `Timer`/`TimerTask` are btw rarely a good idea on android. I'd use a `new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer with effectively no end time. It runs on the ui thread.

Comment: I agree with @zapl, I just run your code on https://try.kotlinlang.org and it works just fine. With your code above, there is exactly one instance created for each execution that is stored in the `task` variable

Comment: @zapl I also doubt I wrote that line twice, but it isn't. And I test one more thing. When I insert `task.cancel` right after timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000), the task didn't work. It is correct. But if I execute `task.cancel` manually(may be it will execute after few seconds), it starts two tasks...    Thanks your answer, and I'll try to use `CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000)`!

Comment: @zapl Oh my.. That code is not problem. Android call the `onCreate` function twice. So, that line executed twice. Thanks for your answer :)